# Blank (locked?) screen after login, no problem when booted in recovery mode

Tags: boot, login, suspend, mate

I have installed ubuntuMATE (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS) on a Lenovo B50-30 laptop, seemingly without problem, 'Linux 4.4.0-53-generic' is listed in GRUB2.

It boots through to the login screen fine where the user I set up is present. I am able to log in with my password and the Ubuntu logo shows whilst the desktop is being set up. Once this is complete I briefly see the desktop before the screen fades to black (blank, no backlight), much like I would expect from a suspended system. I cannot recover the screen from here, but if I hit ctrl+alt+del I can hear a system noise, so the OS has not crashed.

If I boot into recovery mode, select to resume normal boot from the recovery menu (it warns me some graphical drivers may need a full reboot) and follow the same login procedure everything works as intended and the screen remains active. If I suspend the system from this point however, the screen never reactivates.

I have checked that the Intel integrated graphics drivers are up to date (they appear to be) and have trawled this exchange and google, trying the various fixes I find to no avail. Whilst the problem can be worked around using recovery mode a real fix is needed.

I tried installing Kernel 4.4.25 following this guide: 
http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-kernel-4-4-on-ubuntu/

But it shows the same problems.

I'd love any advice for solving this problem, it's aggravating to be so close, and yet so far, from a working system.

Comment: You've seen this I guess? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](//askubuntu.com/q/162075)

Comment: Thank you, but yes, I have. The only route that remains to me from that thread is to start trying to install older kernels and see if they run properly, pretending that an update broke things. I suspect this problem is a simple configuration issue though, given how it momentarily works normally, and works fine in recovery mode. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Oh yeah that's not a solution I'd recommend. I wonder if you've checked out Ubuntu forums to see if there's anyone having the same issue with your hardware, or searched for bug reports? My laptop is a real basketcase and I have to do a lot of weird stuff to get it working well, and all the hacks come from folks on Ubuntu forums. Here on AU hardware-specific questions and those about idiosyncratic problems tend not to get answered; it's just the structure of the site. I've got a feeling you'll be answering your own question when you fix this. Good luck!

Comment: I'll head over there and post. TBH I've exhausted my skills and patience with this one. Asking others is a last resort, I'll start looking at other distros most likely and hope to solve it that way. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to avoid the problem by using the newer kernel in the 16.10 build, rather than fixing 16.04.

[The Ubuntu forums post that led to this answer is here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2346002)

It has some advice for fixing the 16.04 problems. Though I never personally tried beyond an upgrade to 16.10.